# Declaring variables before declaring a function

Tags: matlab, function

Suppose I want to declare some variables then declare a function:

```
x = 2;
function y = function(x)
    y = (x^2)+1;
end
y = function(x);
disp(y)
```

Matlab returns the error "Function keyword use is invalid here..."

Why can't I declare variables or write any text before declaring a function? Is there good reason or is it a quirk?

EDIT:
To clarify, I do know how to get around this problem (but thanks for the suggestions nonetheless) but I suppose I'm asking why the Matlab team made this decision. By making a function declaration the first line of a file, does it have implications for memory management, or something?

Comment: You need to define a function in a new file where `x` isn't defined before the `function` keyword.

Comment: Or use an anonymous function: `fun = @(x) x^2+1;` and then call it like `y = fun(3)` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REPL prompt of Scala can have a function defined after a variable. So this is a choice (a quirk if you want) from Matlab's inner internals.

Answer (score 1):

1. If a function is defined in a file, there are two possibilities:

   - The **main function** of that file. Then the file must begin with the function declaration: in your example, `function y = fun(x)`. I'm using `fun` as the function's name. I don't think `function` can be used as a function's name.

     See [here](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html) for more details.
   - A **nested function**. In this case, the function declaration and definition can be within another function of the preceding case.

     See [here](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) for more details.

   As you can see, in either case the file begins with a function declaration (namely that of the main function).
2. The function can also be defined as an **anonymous function**. Then no declaration is needed, and the function can be defined anywhere. But there's a restriction: the function can contain only a single statement (so it cannot define internal variables other than the output). Therefore this method can only be used for simple functions.

   In your example, the function could be defined anonymously as `fun = @(x) x^2+1`.

   See [here](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Others have given good info about nested functions and such.

But the reason for the error you get is that "function" is a reserved word in Matlab.  You cannot have a function with this name.

```
function y = my_function(x)
    y = (x^2)+1;
end
```

And stick it in another file called my_function.m